# SQL how to inner join on alias

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I am trying to do an inner join on an alias that has additional text onto the value, how would i do this?

This is what i have tried and it doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Inventory] ([VendorName], [PartNumber], [QuantityAvailable]) 
    SELECT 'TestVendor', 'V/P' + [Partnumber] as PartNumber, [QuantityAvailable]
    FROM [dbo].[Bulk_Temp]
    inner join v_PartMaster on Bulk_Temp.PartNumber = v_PartMaster.FullPartNumber
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to use `PartNumber` from the `SELECT` in the `ON` clause.  You need to repeat the expression . . . or use some similar trick:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Inventory (VendorName, PartNumber, QuantityAvailable) 
    SELECT 'TestVendor', 'V/P' + Partnumber as PartNumber, QuantityAvailable
    FROM dbo.Bulk_Temp JOIN
         v_PartMaster 
         ON 'V/P' + PartNumber = v_PartMaster.FullPartNumber;
```